call pwsh from powershell 5.1 and get return value only
My goal is to run a scriptblock with pwsh.exe and get just the return value from it.
$code = 'write-host 999 ; $a = @(1,2,3) ; return $a'

$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($code)

I'd like to see the original $a from the sciptblock here as a return value:
pwsh.exe $sb

But i get this array as a result:
999
999

1
2
3

What would be a solution to this problem?

Assuming Write-Host is the only source of extra output: $sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("function global:Write-Host {};$code")

No, the question is more in general.  $code could be any PowerShell code.

@MathiasR.Jessen, there is something odd in his problem that I'm not getting.  If you do this: $results = pwsh.exe $sb, it results in one 999 being printed, but the the value in $results[0] is 999 and $results[1] is two blank lines.

Note that pwsh.exe $sb doesn’t “return” anything to the caller (windows Powershell 5.1) - all pwsh does it write text to the stdout stream. write-host writes directly to this stream whereas the top-level return $a is implicity piped to out-default which formats the value as a string and writes it to the stdout stream. As a result, output received from pwsh.exe $sb can’t easily be filtered into output from write-host vs return $a because it’s all just a big blob of text lines…

@mclayton:  Can we pipe $a to something else instead of out-default or stdout ?

You could write a json representation to a file  - e.g. Set-Content -Path “c:\somefile.json” -Value ($a | convertto-json) and then read it back with $a = Get-Content -Path “c:\somefile.json” | convertfrom-json?
